# Cannot implicitly convert type System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal to string

Tags: c#, account-management

I've got a variable which is a list of strings

var names = new List();

I want to assign the names of the results of a `.AccountManagement.Principal` query to names

```
 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
 UserPrincipal buser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user);

 if (buser != null)
 {
     var group = buser.GetGroups().Value().ToList();
     names = group;
 }
```

Obviously this does not compile, since `.Value` is not a property of `GetGroups()`.

If I try

```
var group = buser.GetGroups().Value().ToList();
names = group;
```

I get

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal to string

I want to get the value of group and apply it the name a list of strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like `Value()` method/extension method

If you want to get a list of UserNames in a list of string you can do:

```
List<string> userList = buser.GetGroups().Select(r=>r.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Worth a shot:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain); 
UserPrincipal buser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, user); 
if (buser != null) 
{ 
    names = (
        from 
            groupPrincipal in buser.GetGroups() 
        select 
            groupPrincipal.Name
        ).ToList(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no value method.
The statement `buser.GetGroups()` returns a PrincipalSearchResult collection.

```
  PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> group = buser.GetGroups();
```

You can then iterate over the collection,to fetch the names

```
  foreach(Principal pr in group)
     Console.WriteLine(pr.Name);
```